# SQL First() Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using phpMyAdmin to write some SQL code that I thought was simple but proving to be a headache. I'm using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp) tutorial to help me out. My goal is to get the first and last columns id's from a result set. When I do this query I get 5 rows starting at 15 and going through 11.

```
SELECT id
FROM boardPost
WHERE recipientId = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

However, when I try this query I get an error #1064: "You have an error in your SQL syntax."

```
SELECT FIRST(id)
FROM boardPost
WHERE recipientId = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Why would you fetch 5 rows if you just want the first ID? Why not just fetch just the 1 row you need?

Comment: Don't use w3schools it's full of errors. MySQL doesn't have a `first()` function (which isn't a standard SQL function anyway). You probably want: `min(id)`

Comment: I tried min but then it gave me the min in the entire table. I just need the min for that particular result set

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting all of these downvotes but I got what I needed. Thank you all very much for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT min(id), max(id)
from (
  select id
  from boardPost
  where recipientId = 1
  order by id desc
  limit 0,5
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that is what you want?

```
Select id from boardPost order by id asc limit 1
```

and

```
Select id from boardPost order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: The problem with this is I do not know the boundaries of my result set

Comment: @gmustudent what do you mean by not knowing the boundaries? do you want to get the first and the last row of the whole table?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first and the last `id` of a result set, you could consider this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) firstId, MAX(id) lastId FROM someTable WHERE aField = 1;
```

Note that it'll only work if you do use **and `ORDER BY`** an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, else you might get unexpected results.

It'll only work with the full set. If you need the first and last `id` of a limited one, you're probably better of using 2 queries with `ASC` and `DESC` order and `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: I tried min but it gave me the min in the entire table. I just need the min for that particular result set

Comment: @gmustudent is right. If he has to sort it by (for example) a string and get the first result then min(id) would get the minimal id and NOT the first row

Comment: The problem with your update is I do not know the boundaries of my result set

Comment: @ITroubs I forgot to mention that you had to `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Comment: @GuidoH IF you order by a numeric value then your answer is perfectly save. BUT otherways the min and max might end up doing something you don't want...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support the `FIRST()` function. You will need to use the workaround they specified in that tutorial (using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`)

Answer (score 1):

In some situations (like mine, that first brought me here), there are some rarely-used MySQL *["windowing functions"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)* such as **[`FIRST_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value)** and **[`LAST_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_last-value)** that may provide the functionality you're seeking.

(Here's more info on [Window Function Concepts and Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), and the [Wikipedia description](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) of the term.)